Has Blue Origin carried out any flight or landing tests of the New Glenn first stage?
New Glenn is scheduled to launch the EscaPADE probe to Mars in the September launch window.  I've read a lot about ground systems testing and prospective BE-4 static fire tests, but can't find anything concerning in-flight testing or precision landing tests for the first stage.  I know Blue Origin have controlled landing experience from New Shepard, but is that enough to allow them to land on the Landing Platform Vessel?

From all articles, no. The first flight, is the first launch, in September. Currently, last activity I read about were the hotfire tests.

I would expect them to want to get at least one launch accomplished in order to gain data on flight characteristics before they do any flight tests related to recovery. This would be similar to SpaceX, the first Falcon 9 test flight was in 2010 but the first grasshopper test wasn't until 2012, with the first booster landing test the following year. They did initially experiment with parachutes in early Falcon 9 flights, but I think even if they had planned propulsive recovery from the beginning I doubt SpaceX would have begun flight tests for it until after Falcon 9 had launched at least once.

@StevePemberton, the first Falcon 9 recovery test was also in 2010, on the first flight.  SpaceX didn't start flying Grasshopper until they determined that ballistic re-entry with parachute recovery wouldn't work.

@Mark - yes I mentioned the parachute experiments, I was referring to tests related to propulsive landing. Maybe on the first New Glenn flight they will attempt to keep the booster stable during reentry, but I would be surprised if there were any tests related to propulsive landing. That just seems like a lot to put on the plate for the first flight. True that SpaceX listed that on the card for IFT-1, but I suspect they didn't put a lot of time planning test objectives for it on the first flight and instead concentrated on the launch. But who knows, maybe Bezos wants an end-to-end test.

No, Blue Origin has not carried out any flight or landing tests of the New Glenn first stage.
They have conducted hotfire tests of their BE-3 and BE-4 engines, as well as cryogenic testing as LC-36, but have not conducted flight or landing tests.
They are currently planning for the inaugural launch to happen on September 29, 2024, which will be the first flight test of any kind for New Glenn.
Edit: As Jörg W Mittag commented, there have indeed been flight tests involving the BE-4 engines New Glenn will use in its first stage. ULA's Vulcan Centaur Cert-1 mission launched a payload to the moon in February, where the Vulcan first stage's BE-4 engines worked seemingly flawlessly.

They also performed the rather impressive trick of not only having one of their competitors perform a full-duration in-space hot-fire test of the BE-4, but even make them pay for it!
